Daily digests of Mathematica SE emails no longer arriving. How to get them back?
I used to get daily (or more frequent) email digests of recent questions. Somehow I must have accidentally unsubscribed from those.
Can anyone tell me how to get them back.  I set up anew “Digest” on my profile, but it only has “weekly” as an option.

Nevermind, I found it at https://stackexchange.com/filters/
